# Exibir dados da sessionStorage em uma div

Tags: javascript, formulário, div, localstorage

Estou fazendo uma atividade que consiste em gravar dados obtidos de um formulário na sessionStorage com o botão Cadastrar, e com o botão Exibir, mostrar os dados gravados. Não consigo mostrar esses dados gravados na div. Como posso fazer?

**Aqui está o que eu fiz até agora**

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    document.querySelector("#cad").addEventListener("click", cadastrar);
    document.querySelector("#exibir").addEventListener("click", exibir);

})

function cadastrar() {
    if(typeof(sessionStorage) == 'undefined'){
        alert("Seu navegador não suporta HTML5 localStorage.")
    }else{
    var nome = window.sessionStorage.setItem("nome", $("#nome").val());
    var rgm = window.sessionStorage.setItem("rgm", $("#rgm").val());
    var par = window.sessionStorage.setItem("nota_parcial", $("#nota_parcial").val());
    var pro = window.sessionStorage.setItem("nota_pro", $("#nota_pro").val());
    var reg = window.sessionStorage.setItem("nota_regi", $("#nota_regi").val());

    }
}

function exibir(){
    if (sessionStorage.length > 0){
    var result = $("#resp");

    onome =  $("#nome").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nome"));
    orgm =  $("#rgm").val(sessionStorage.getItem("rgm"));
    npar =  $("#nota_parcial").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nota_parcial"));
    npro =  $("#nota_pro").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nota_pro"));
    nreg =  $("#nota_regi").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nota_regi"));

   result.innerHTML += onome;
   result.innerHTML += orgm;
   result.innerHTML += npar;
   result.innerHTML += npro;
   result.innerHTML += nreg;
    }else{
        alert("Nada foi Gravado!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que você está os objetos de forma errada. Por exemplo, a variável `var result = $("#resp");` é um objeto jQuery que não usa `.innerHTML`. Para inserir HTML em um elemento com objeto jQuery usa-se `.html()` e não `.innerHTML`.

Outra coisa é que você está pegando os valores dos campos de forma errada. Por exemplo, a variável `onome =  $("#nome").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nome"));` irá retornar o elemento `$("#nome")`, e não o seu valor.

Há algumas formas de resolver isso, e uma delas é criar uma nova variável com os valores utilizando `.val()` e depois usar `.html()` para exibir esses valores na div:

```
var dados = onome.val()
+ orgm.val()
+ npar.val()
+ npro.val()
+ nreg.val();

result.html(dados);
```

Na variável `dados` você pode, inclusive, colocar `<br>` para separar os dados por linhas:

```
var dados = onome.val() + '<br>'
+ orgm.val() + '<br>'
+ npar.val() + '<br>'
+ npro.val() + '<br>'
+ nreg.val();

result.html(dados);
```

O código da função `exibir()` ficaria assim:

```
function exibir(){
    if (sessionStorage.length > 0){
    var result = $("#resp");

    onome =  $("#nome").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nome"));
    orgm =  $("#rgm").val(sessionStorage.getItem("rgm"));
    npar =  $("#nota_parcial").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nota_parcial"));
    npro =  $("#nota_pro").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nota_pro"));
    nreg =  $("#nota_regi").val(sessionStorage.getItem("nota_regi"));

   var dados = onome.val() + '<br>'
   + orgm.val() + '<br>'
   + npar.val() + '<br>'
   + npro.val() + '<br>'
   + nreg.val();

   result.html(dados);

    }else{
        alert("Nada foi Gravado!");
    }
}
```